# mysql.connector do not give the last database state in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sql-update

I use `mysql.connector` library in Python to send query to database. But, when the database is changed after the initialization, the `mysql.connector`’s tools answer like if the database had never change.

As example, let’s imagine I have a minimalist table `students` with just two columns `id` and `name`.

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
| 0  | foo  |
+----+------+
```

In the following code, the query will ask the user with `id` 0. But, inside the process, some events will happened from outside the Python script and alter the database.

```
import mysql.connector

maindb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host = "<host>",
    user = "<user>",
    password = "<password>",
    db = "<database name>"
)

cursor = maindb.cursor()

# Here, I will send outside the python script a MySQL query to modify the name of the student from “foo” to “bar” like this:
# `UPDATE `students` SET `name` = 'bar' WHERE `students`.`id` = 0;`

cursor.execute("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `students` WHERE `id` = 0")
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```

Then I get this answer `[(0, 'foo')]`. As you see, Python is not aware the data base has change since `maindb.cursor()` was called. So I get `foo` as name field instead of `bar` as expected.

So how to tell `mysql.connector`’s tools to take the last updates from the database when I send a query?

Comment: Make sure all changes are commited and open a new cursor.

Comment: the Python script just `SELECT` data. The `UPDATE` statement was made outside Python, directly from the MySQL client for the test.

Comment: @KlausD. I also try to `.close()` the cursor and retry the process since `cursor = maindb.cursor()` but the behavior still the same.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a socket or if the changes occur frequently have your code re-run every x minutes

Answer (score 1):

I just need to `.connect()` `maindb` object and `.close()` it before each new need.

```
maindb.connect()

cursor.execute("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `students` WHERE `id` = 0")
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)

maindb.close()
```

Comment: I have been battling this issue for a whole day now and this answer really helped me out. I had to close my DB connection and initialize it again inside my endless while loop. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 1):

The database maintains data integrity by preventing in-progress transactions from seeing changes made by other transactions (see [transaction isolation levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)).

You can `commit` your connection to allow it to see new changes:

```py
cursor = maindb.cursor()


# Here, I will send outside the python script a MySQL query to modify the name of the student from “foo” to “bar” like this:
# `UPDATE `students` SET `name` = 'bar' WHERE `students`.`id` = 0;`

# Doesn't show the update
cursor.execute("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `students` WHERE `id` = 0")
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)  

# Shows the update because we have committed.
maindb.commit()
cursor.execute("SELECT `id`, `name` FROM `students` WHERE `id` = 0")
result = cursor.fetchall()
print(result)
```